# sms or phone authentication stopped sending OTP after some time

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We create 5-7 envelopes with 18-20 recipients. Every recipient uses phone authentication before continuing with the signing process.

So DocuSign may need to send over 100 sms or phone calls within 2 hours.

One signer might be get several OTP’s in a short period

A lot of signers informed us that after signing some envelopes in a row the DocuSign stops sending OTP for the verification process.

We have bought the following product
APT-0018 / SMS - Usage Subscription / 6500 QT

Has the DocuSign any limitation issue about the OTP ?

Comment: Is this for the same phone number? there are protections against spam so if you sent 100 texts to the same number that number may not be getting texts anymore.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: The signer wait for the OPT but nothing happened. The same signer 
 with the same phone number, tried to access some documents (Different envelopes) with phone authentication method at least 10-20 times in a few minutes.

Comment: Can you try a different number? It's possible this number has a block because of suspicious activity

Comment: Is there a way to unblock a number? Does it unblock after a period of time? I've run into the same issue while testing an integration, and now I'm left without a way to sign documents. I've hit the 100 sms cap in about two days.

Comment: you will need to contact customer support

Answer (score 0):

There are protection limits set it place to avoid spam. These can all be modified if there's a need or if there's an issue. The best way to fix the issue is to contact our customer support service and open a case with them. You can do that by going to https://support.docusign.com